# Java libgdx 2.5D

Tags: libgdx

so I'm trying to make 2.5D game and I want to make that players could hide behind objects (like walls, fountains, other players which are closer to camera).

Preview of what i'm tying to say: [image]

So I want to ask some suggestions/help how could I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very vague question but a basic idea will be manipulation of the background and foreground. You will need to be able to change where your character falls and whether or not the an object can be both foreground or background. If they can be both then you could declare that as a object that could be hidden behind.

Answer (score 0):

I propose some solution that you could try :

with libgdx to draw an Object1 before an other Object2 you just render the object1 and then render the Object2 but to manipulate distance like you want to do, you should try to use Masking with Depth buffer
see an example in the officiel docs

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking

also not very efficient but you could try :
I once try to make some object look in the background comparing to each other, so i played with their opacity color, it worked fine for what I needed

hope that was helpful good luck